# WP_DEBUG must be on, otherwise edit post or page will show 404 error

Tags: 404-error, wp-debug

encountered a very strange error: my WP_DEBUG must be on (set to true), otherwise editing post or page at the admin panel will show the 404 error. While the save post/page can still be seen.

The wordpress version is 5.6.

What might be the underlining cause of this error? Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Really a 404 or the WP error message? If you also turn on `WP_DEBUG_LOG`, do you see any messages in the error log?

Comment: Yes, a 404 error page after click "edit" of post and page. Whenever WP_DEBUG is false, it's 404 error. After it's true, then can access. WP_DEBUG_LOG shows some warnings, still looking for the solution.